# VBA - overall results for variable named tabs and different standards

Tags: vba, variables, excel, spreadsheet

So, I created a spreadsheet with 2 different kinds of flowcharts.
The user type the number of how many flowcharts from each he needs, and it multiplies automatically, so the user can fill out the data in each one.
On the top of each flowchart has a line with the results from it.
Till here everything works perfectly.
Now, I need to create a tab with the overall results from each flowchart created, the problems I am facing are:
1)Each tab will be renamed by the user
- So I thought I could create a code to get the results using the codename of the sheets (sheet1, etc), but it also doesn't work bc:
2) There are 2 different types of flowchart (it means 2 different standards of results, with different number of rows, etc), and the number of sheets that the user will create for each one is also unknowing.

I am really lost in here, and I would really appreciate your help!

p.s. I am really new with macros, so I am not really familiar with VBA.

'
'Ausführung bei klick auf den Button "Anzahl Bauteile eingeben"
'
Private Sub CommandButton4_Click()

```
'Insert Blatt
Dim InAnzahl As Integer, intI As Integer, insL As Integer, insR As Integer, ws As Worksheet
InAnzahl = Application.InputBox("Anzahl der Prozesse (eingeben", "Kopie", 0, Type:=1)
If InAnzahl = 0 Then Exit Sub
If InAnzahl = 1 Then Sheets("Prozessbewertung").Select
For intI = 1 To InAnzahl - 1
    Sheets("Prozessbewertung").Select
    Sheets("Prozessbewertung").Copy after:=Sheets(ActiveSheet.Name)
Next intI

 'Insert Lines (ALSO UPDATED)
If InAnzahl > 2 Then Sheets("Gesamtbewertung").Select
For insL = 1 To InAnzahl - 1
Sheets("Gesamtbewertung").Rows("11:11").Insert shift:=xlDown,
CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
Next insL
```

UPDATE:

I created the program below to insert the results (but it's limited under the number of line I will create in the program)
Also, I still don't know how to make excel understand I have 2 different standards of results, so I created only for one.

Sub Ergebnisse()

```
'Prozessbewertung Blatt 1
Sheets(5).[C3:AL3].Copy Sheets(3).[C10:AL10]
'Prozessbewertung Blatt 2
Sheets(6).[C3:AL3].Copy Sheets(3).[C11:AL11]
'Prozessbewertung Blatt 3
Sheets(7).[C3:AL3].Copy Sheets(3).[C12:AL12]
'Prozessbewertung Blatt 4
Sheets(8).[C3:AL3].Copy Sheets(3).[C13:AL13]
```

End Sub

and so on...

Somebody to help? I could not solve this yet! Please!

Comment: Can you explain how you would do this manually? Would you write a formula that referred to the sheet? Or copy and paste from each sheet to the summary sheet? I'm trying to figure out what the 'overall results' look like.

Comment: So, manually I would have to go thru each sheet of flowchart created by the user to copy the header results from the flowchart and paste in the Overall Results. Since I have two different types of flowcharts, I have also 2 different tables in the Overall Results:
First: C10 till AL10 (add lines)
Second: H26 till W26 (add lines)
The problem is to find a way to explain excel that I don’t know how many flowcharts will be created for each type, but anyways he need to know how to copy and paste the results in the right table of the overall results

Answer (score 0):

Well since I found no solution for this, I decided to split the 2 different standards of results in 2 different excel sheets.